# Using forms authentication, how do I handle redirection to a different subdomaim

Tags: asp.net, subdomain, formsauthentication

I have multiple sub-domains that use forms authentication.  Once a user logs in, they are fine going to any of the other sub-domains.

Here is my problem:  If I go to reporting.example.com/reporting.aspx, I get redirected to login.example.com/login.aspx.  After entering my credentials, I get redirected to **login**.example.com/reporting.aspx, which doesn't exist.

I have a work around but I would like to know if there is a cleaner way.  What I do currently is set the loginUrl attribute of the forms element of the reporting.example.com to be login.example.com/login.aspx?domain=reporting.example.com.

Then, in the login.aspx code, after I've authenticated and set the cookie, I look to see if there was a domain variable passed in to the URL.  If so, I prepend the returnUrl with the domain and do a simple redirect.

It works, but it feels klugey.  Any ideas?

Comment: That's pretty much the best way to do it. Otherwise your only other practical option is to work with referers, and they're about 10% reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Does the ReturnURL contain the full url?  If so it should work as expected..

Make sure you have [EnableCrossAppRedirects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.enablecrossappredirects.aspx) set to true in your web.config.

Comment: Unfortunately, the returnUrl is relative to the home directory of the calling application.  In my example, returnUrl is /reporting.aspx.

Comment: It looks like this code will put the full URL in the RedirectURL:http://weblogs.asp.net/dfindley/archive/2007/02/06/fix-returnurl-when-sharing-forms-authentication-with-multiple-web-applications.aspx